# Android, Flurry, and endTimedEvent

Tags: android, flurry

The Flurry SDK for iOS has a method `[Flurry endTimedEvent:@"EVENT_NAME" withParameters:YOUR_NSDictionary]`. Is there an equivalent way to implement this functionality in Android?

I'm aware that you can *start* a timed event with parameters using `FlurryAgent.logEvent("EVENT_NAME", myDictionary, true)`, but I'd like to update the values in the dictionary before ending the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently supported by the Android SDK. I've made a note of it, thanks for the suggestion.

(disclaimer: I work on the Android SDK at Flurry)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I hope you can implement it soon! (And please, include the Javadocs when you export the next version of the SDK - it's nice to be able see definitions and parameters for Flurry method calls from Eclipse)

Comment: any progress on this? seems like it's still not supported in Flurry, am I right?

Comment: There's an endTimedEvent method: 
http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/android/classcom_1_1flurry_1_1android_1_1_flurry_agent.html#ad569f2059e09e0266aec5cadcdba3ef1